# Best precious stone from an ROI standpoint?

Tags: precious-metals, jewelry

I'm wondering what kind of jewelry-grade mineral (excluding precious metals) would be the least risky investment. So the binding requirement is: it has to be jewelry-worthy (so both pretty and not too fragile - beryls are OK). The ROI can be negative, in which case I would be interested in knowing the least negative ROI. Please assume no special access to a closed market - the buyer would buy and sell retail.

Comment: With this week's [episode of Freakonomics Radio](http://freakonomics.com/2015/04/16/diamonds-are-a-marriage-counselors-best-friend-a-new-freakonomics-radio-podcast/) (which explained how a diamond's value is not intrinsic but rather due entirely to industry-imposed supply constraints) in mind, are you asking for a comparison of the recent history of supply/demand for these minerals?  Or are you trying to get at a list of minerals for which all known reserves have been tapped?

Comment: Depends on fashion (preferred stones change, preferred cuts change and recutting loses part of the stone) . Depends on what has been happening recently with availability of both natural and "made" stones. If anyone actually knew the answer, it would probably skew the value of the stones until that answer was invalidated again...

Comment: So is this essentially a question of whether to buy Diamond, Sapphire, Ruby, Pearls, Opals, Topaz? Well it depends. There is nothing called BEST. Its similar to asking which is the best stock to buy from an ROI standpoint.